# Density over histogram using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have "long" format data frame which contains two columns: first col - values, second col- sex [Male - 1/Female - 2]. I wrote some code to make a histogram of entire dataset (code below).

```
ggplot(kz6, aes(x = values)) + 
  geom_histogram()
```

However, I want also add a density over histogram to emphasize the difference between sexes i.e. I want to combine 3 plots: histogram for entire dataset, and 2 density plots for each sex. I tried to use some examples ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41368580/density-curve-over-plotly-histogram), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35443396/overlaying-exponential-density-over-histogram-of-data), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061653/creating-a-density-histogram-in-ggplot2/21069799), [four](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~luke/classes/STAT4580-2020/histdens.html)), but it still does not work. Code for density only works, while the combinations of hist + density does not.

```
density <- ggplot(kz6, aes(x = x, fill = factor(sex))) + 
  geom_density()

both <- ggplot(kz6, aes(x = values)) + 
  geom_histogram() +
  geom_density()

both_2 <- ggplot(kz6, aes(x = values)) + 
  geom_histogram() +
  geom_density(aes(x = kz6[kz6$sex == 1,]))
```

P.S. some examples contains `y=..density..` what does it mean? How to interpret this?

Comment: Does one of the answers posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688082/overlay-histogram-with-density-curve) suit your needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To plot a histogram and superimpose two densities, defined by a categorical variable, use appropriate aesthetics in the call to `geom_density`, like `group` or `colour`.

```
ggplot(kz6, aes(x = values)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), bins = 20) +
  geom_density(aes(group = sex, colour = sex), adjust = 2)
```

[image]

**Data creation code.**

I will create a test data set from built-in data set `iris`.

```
kz6 <- iris[iris$Species != "virginica", 4:5]
kz6$sex <- "M"
kz6$sex[kz6$Species == "versicolor"] <- "F"
kz6$Species <- NULL
names(kz6)[1] <- "values"
head(kz6)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but could you explain me how ```y = ..density..``` and what does it mean?

Comment: @HermanCherniaiev In `help("geom_histogram")` section `Computed variables` there are several variables. Put any of them between two dots to gain access to their values. `..density..` is the one you want.